# *ngIf is not working properly

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ng-if

HTML

```html
<figure class="daysearch-cover__image">
      <img src="fh.jpg" *ngIf="!showBirthdayTheme">
      <img src="fhbt.jpg" *ngIf="showBirthdayTheme">
</figure>
```

I'm logging that showBirthdayTheme variable in console. Its clearly coming that the value is true but "fh.jpg" is loading instead of "fhbt.jpg".

I'm not able to understand whats going wrong here.

EDIT: adding component code
I'm very new to angular and kindly correct me if I've done anything blunder.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFire, AuthProviders, AuthMethods, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2';


declare const FB : any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Themes POC!';

  items: FirebaseListObservable<any>;
  name: any;
  msgVal: string = '';
  userName: string = '';
  photoURL : string = '';
  graphPhotoURL : string = '';
  showNasLogin: any;
  showLogoutMessage: any;
  dob : string = '';
  showBirthdayTheme: boolean = false;
  theme: String= '';

  constructor(public af: AngularFire) {
    this.items = af.database.list('/messages', {
      query: {
        limitToLast: 50
      }
    });

    this.af.auth.subscribe(auth => {
      if(auth) {
        this.name = auth;
        this.userName = auth.facebook.displayName;
        this.photoURL = auth.facebook.photoURL;
        this.graphPhotoURL = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + auth.facebook.uid + "/picture?height=67&width=70";
        this.dob = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + auth.facebook.uid + "/birthday";
      }
    });

  }


  setShowNasLogin(): void {
    console.log("inside setShowNasLogin");
    this.showNasLogin = "yes";
    this.showLogoutMessage = null;
    this.name = null;
  }

  resetShowNasLogin(): void {
    console.log("inside resetShowNasLogin");
    this.showNasLogin = undefined;
    this.name = undefined;
    this.showLogoutMessage = "yes";
  }

  login(){

    //retrieving DOB
    this.onFBLogin();

    this.af.auth.login({
      provider: AuthProviders.Facebook,
      method: AuthMethods.Popup
    });

  }

  logout(){
    this.af.auth.logout().then( () => {
      console.log(this.graphPhotoURL);
                                        this.name = null;
                                        this.userName = '';
                                        this.photoURL = '';
                                        this.graphPhotoURL = '';
                                        this.showBirthdayTheme = false;
                                        console.log("Successfully logged out")
                                      } );
    this.resetShowNasLogin();
  }

  chatSend(desc: string){
    this.items.push({message: desc, name: this.name.facebook.displayName});
    this.msgVal = '';
  }

  onFBLogin() {
    console.log("Trying to get birthdate");

  FB.login( function(response) {
    console.log("inside FB.login");
    if(response.authResponse) {
      FB.api('/me', 'GET', {fields: 'email, first_name, name, id, picture, birthday'}, function(response) {
        console.log("User's DOB:"+ response.birthday);
        var birthDate = new Date(response.birthday+'');
        var currentDate = new Date();
        birthDate.setFullYear(currentDate.getFullYear());
        if(birthDate < currentDate){
          birthDate.setFullYear(birthDate.getFullYear()+1);
        }
        var diff = birthDate.getTime()-currentDate.getTime();
        var days = Math.floor(diff/(1000*60*60*24));
        console.log("No of days left for "+response.name+"'s birthday :"+days);

        //if birth month is with in coming 2 months
        if(days < 40){
          console.log("setting theme");
          this.showBirthdayTheme = true;
        }
        console.log("showBirthdayTheme:" +this.showBirthdayTheme);
        if(this.showBirthdayTheme){
          console.log("Birthday theme should be displayed");
        }
        else{
          console.log("Default theme should be displayed");
        }

      });
    }
    else{
      //error
      console.log("Errored while trying to connect to facebook");
    }
  }, {
    scope: 'email, user_birthday',
    return_scopes: true
  }
  );

}

  /*selectTheme(){
    /!*this.dobRes = this.dob.split("/");
    console.log(this.dobRes[0]);*!/

    var birthDate = new Date(this.dob);
    console.log("user birthday:"+birthDate);
    console.log(birthDate.getMonth());
  }*/
}
```

Changed the function call as suggested:

```
 FB.login( function(response) {
```

changed to below

FB.login( (response)=> {

The log is as below:

```
app.component.ts:48 inside setShowNasLogin
app.component.ts:92 Trying to get birthdate
app.component.ts:95 inside FB.login
app.component.ts:98 User's DOB:06/01/1990
app.component.ts:107 No of days left for Ravi Teja Gubba's birthday :36
app.component.ts:111 setting theme
app.component.ts:114 showBirthdayTheme:true
app.component.ts:116 Birthday theme should be displayed
```

Comment: can you add the component side?

Comment: `*ngIf` is working fine. The issue comes from somewhere else.

Comment: try `ng-if="showBirthdayTheme"`

Comment: @Torben that's how it's done in Angular v1, OP is (hopefully) using Angular v2

Comment: are you sure showBirthdayTheme is boolean type. check the type. If it is string then check for string like *ngIf="showBirthdayTheme==='true'"

Comment: Can you please try to use [src]="'fh.jpg'" and [src]="'fhbt.jpg'" and see if it solves the issue?

Comment: Is `showBirthdayTheme` true from the very beginning or is it set dynamically later on? If it's set later on, angular's change detection might not capture it for some reason.

Comment: can you put {{showBirthdayTheme}} in your template ? To be sure it is true/false when needed.

Comment: It is impossible to find the problem here if you don't show your component.ts

Comment: Please, share your component code so we can find the root of the issue, as the use of *ngIf is correct. The problem probably lies within the component code and the value of **showBirthdayTheme**.

Answer (score 3):

You are using regular functions in your FB.login and FB.api calls. So `this` value points to function object and not the class.So `this.showBirthdayTheme = true;` will not set the class variable.

Try arrow function `()=>{}` for such callbacks

```
FB.login((response)=> {//here
    console.log("inside FB.login");
    if(response.authResponse) {
      FB.api('/me', 'GET', {fields: 'email, first_name, name, id, picture, birthday'}, (response)=>{//here
        console.log("User's DOB:"+ response.birthday);
        var birthDate = new Date(response.birthday+'');
        var currentDate = new Date();
        birthDate.setFullYear(currentDate.getFullYear());
        if(birthDate < currentDate){
          birthDate.setFullYear(birthDate.getFullYear()+1);
        }
        var diff = birthDate.getTime()-currentDate.getTime();
        var days = Math.floor(diff/(1000*60*60*24));
        console.log("No of days left for "+response.name+"'s birthday :"+days);

        //if birth month is with in coming 2 months
        if(days < 40){
          console.log("setting theme");
          this.showBirthdayTheme = true;
        }
        console.log("showBirthdayTheme:" +this.showBirthdayTheme);
        if(this.showBirthdayTheme){
          console.log("Birthday theme should be displayed");
        }
        else{
          console.log("Default theme should be displayed");
        }

      });
       //...
```

Comment: This is correct, every new regular function defines its own value for `this`, use fat arrow functions or bound functions to avoid this behavior.

Comment: I tried changing the way you suggested. But it didn't worked :(

Comment: @RavitejaGubba check my answer again.. you have to change at _two_ places

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
<figure class="daysearch-cover__image">
      <img src="fh.jpg" *ngIf="!showBirthdayTheme; else whatIfYes">
<ng-template #whatIfYes>
      <img src="fhbt.jpg">
</ng-template>
</figure>
```

Comment: The template code in the original question is just fine, the problem must be something else.

Answer (score -2):

I have also faced same issue. Don't know the reason. But you can use ng-show instead of ng-if. That works fine.

Comment: There is no `ng-show` or `ng-if` in Angular2 or Angular4